# Properly adding a SBT subproject to a Scala Play project

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework, sbt

I'm trying to leverage some existing code with a new Scala Play project. I'm attempting to do this by adding the existing project as a sub-project to my Scala Play project by following the instructions [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/SBTSubProjects#Adding-a-simple-library-sub-project).

However, I am unable to figure out how to access objects in the subproject from the parent project. For example, I'm trying to create Scala Play singleton object that provides an instance of an object from the subproject.

```
package services
import javax.inject.Singleton

@Singleton
class EngineProvider {

  var instance: Engine = _

  def getEngine: Engine = {
    if (instance == null) {
      instance = new ScalaPlayEngine()
    }
    instance
  }
}
```

However, my Intellij cannot find a way to import `Engine`, or `ScalaPlayEngine` (both objects are from my subproject). I can "trick" Intellij into removing it's errors by importing the following:

```
import _root_.Engine
import _root_.ScalaPlayEngine
```

But when I actually try to run the Play project, I still get an error:

```
play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException: Compilation error[_root_ cannot be imported]
        at play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException$.apply(PlayExceptions.scala:27)
        at play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException$.apply(PlayExceptions.scala:27)
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
        at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$taskFailureHandler$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:49)
        at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$taskFailureHandler$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:44)
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
        at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.taskFailureHandler(PlayReload.scala:44)
        at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.compileFailure(PlayReload.scala:40)
        at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$compile$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:17)
        at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$compile$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:17)
```

My parent (Scala Play) project `build.sbt` file contains this:

```
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .enablePlugins(PlayScala)
  .aggregate(engine)
  .dependsOn(engine)

lazy val engine = project
```

so I would have expected it to be able to pick up any objects from the sub project (since it depends on it). My project structure looks something like this:

```
ParentScalaPlayProject
  build.sbt
  app
    services
      EngineProvider.scala
  .
  .
  .
  engine (child project)
    build.sbt
    src
      main
        scala
          Engine.scala
          ScalaPlayEngine.scala
    .
    .
    .
```

I'm very new to both SBT and Scala Play, so it's very likely I'm missing something obvious here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The error message says `_root_ cannot be imported`. What happens if you put your `Engine` and `ScalaPlayEngine` classes in a proper package, instead of having them in the root package? (`src/main/scala` doesn't count as a package)

Comment: @jqno I added a package "garbage" (`src/main/scala/garbage`), and it started working. Do you know why it doesn't work without that intermediate package? Thank you so much by the way. If you post this as answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Glad it worked! I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error message says: `Compilation error[_root_ cannot be imported]`

According to the [Scala Language Specification, Section 9.2](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/09-top-level-definitions.html#packagings):

> Top-level definitions outside a packaging are assumed to be injected into a special empty package. That package cannot be named and therefore cannot be imported. However, members of the empty package are visible to each other without qualification.

And indeed, your classes `Engine` and `ScalaPlayEngine` don't live in a package (`src/main/scala` doesn't count as a package). If you move them to a proper package, it should work.